# Why can't OSX find my JDK?

Tags: java, macos, gcc, rubygems

I have found my JDK at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk`

I have this in my .bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I have saved my changes with `source .bash_profile`

Now when I try to run `sudo apt get install gcc`

I get this error

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7):

Since this is more about gcc not installing as a result of not finding the java jdk, you'll want to find the current version of java used as default:

```
ls -l `which java`
```

To locate a specific version use (1.8 for example):

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
```

To locate all versions installed:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

You'll need to update your PATH to reflect the location of the jdk (normally for 1.8.0 it should be):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

You would add that to your `~/.bash_profile` and should be back in business.

Further info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1170/_index.html

Answer (score -1):

For Mac users once you download and install JDK:

1. Go to Desktop
2. Press `Command+Shift+G`
3. In the dialogue box type `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`
4. Click `Go`
5. You will find the JDK installed on your system